# Excel VBA Code - Opening file from network folder - PC vs. Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to adapt code to work on both PC and Macs and am running into an issue with accessing a file on a network folder.  Below is the code that currently works properly for PC users.  I know the syntax of the filepath is different for Macs but I can't seem to get it right.  Could I ask for assistance with what changes I need to make?

```
Dim filename1 As String
Dim Path1 As String
Dim Name1 As String
Path1 = "\\Spr1rfpfil\groupdata\admin\sales\Database Share\Data Files\Misc Archive\"
Name1 = "Q4Data.xlsx"
filename1 = Path1 & Name1
Workbooks.Open fileName:=filename1
```

As this is my first posting, please let me know if I should do anything differently in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like 'Application.OperatingSystem'

This would show your environment, then test and set paths accordingly

```
Dim filename1 As String: Dim Path1 As String: Dim Name1 As String

if instr(1, Application.OperatingSystem, "Mac", vbtextcompare) > 0 then
    Path1 = "/Volumes/Spr1rfpfil/groupdata/admin/sales/Database\ Share/Data\ Files/Misc\ Archive/" ' Replace with Mac path
Else
    Path1 = "\\Spr1rfpfil\groupdata\admin\sales\Database Share\Data Files\Misc Archive\" ' Replace with Windows path
End if

Name1 = "Q4Data.xlsx"
filename1 = Path1 & Name1
Workbooks.Open fileName:=filename1
```

Comment: That is great, it definitely recognizes the OS and picks one or the other accordingly.  The issue now is that it still can't locate the file.  Anything I can try to change about the filepath to get it to work?

Comment: If you ran it on the Mac I just noticed I messed up some of the file path - Have edited it so it should now be correct. If it's still not working double check your file path(s).

Answer (score 0):

VBA has a conditional compiler constant for detecting the hosting OS which you can use like this:

```
Dim filename1 As String: Dim Path1 As String: Dim Name1 As String

#If Mac Then
    Path1 = "/Volumes/Spr1rfpfil/groupdata/admin/sales/Database\ Share/Data\ Files/Misc\ Archive/" ' Replace with Mac path
#Else
    Path1 = "\\Spr1rfpfil\groupdata\admin\sales\Database Share\Data Files\Misc Archive\" ' Replace with Windows path
#End if

Name1 = "Q4Data.xlsx"
filename1 = Path1 & Name1
Workbooks.Open fileName:=filename1
```